# Dropdown list <select> tag

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

please anyone give some code to use a png  as drop down arrow, that's goin to suppurt all major browsers. I'm weak in JS so please give me some tutorial.

Comment: please find solution at below link http://kp.bumbleb.in/Default.aspx

Comment: @Zeta How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.adamcoulombe.info/lab/jquery/select-box/).

Comment: Its simple, need to tweak, thanks a lot [xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz)

Comment: @[xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) Yes, for me its perfect... Huge thanks to u...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery can make things easier with a lack of js.  Here is a collection of custom select box plugins that should be pretty easy to implement.

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-form-select-boxes/

Or just try googling 'custom selectbox plugin'.